# How do I stop Appium/Python script hanging when connecting to app?

Tags: python, ios, appium

I have an Appium script (written in Python) which freezes when connecting the web driver.

It is at the following line of code:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Remote(self.webdriver_url,
        desired_capabilities=self.desired_capabilities)
```

I am using the following url:
    http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub

I am trying to connect to an iOS app (with version 9.3). The app has a login screen which comes up first, but bypasses that if the app has already been logged into. When I run the script against the app without it being logged in, the script runs fine. However, if the app has already signed in then the script hangs upon connecting with the above line of code.

Also, if I run the script from a clean installation of the app, my script works fine until it has logged in. Then it gets stuck waiting.

What can I do at this point? Surely, Appium should be able to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should deal with it , not Appium.You should design the test cases run independently,i mean test case 002 should not depend on test case 001.You will need clean installation for each testcase.

Eg: u want to test order test case (005),you should repeat the actions from test case login (001).It will keep you less pain in the future when something change.